# Is compensation for European flight cancellation taxable in India?

Tags: taxes, india

Here is the situation: Indian resident receives compensation (under [EC Regulation 261/2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004)) for cancelled flights while on business travel within EU. Is it taxable in India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best consult a CA. Generally it would be treated as reimbursement of expenses. Hardship you encountered and potentially spent more.

There is no explicit mention of this in Tax rules and is in grey area.